# Unable to refer portlet actionURL inside struts2 tabbedpanel

Tags: struts2, struts, liferay-6, portlet

Issue: I am unable to access portlet action URL from within  panel in my struts2 liferay portlet.

Description:
I need to access "var"

```
<portlet:actionURL var="Overview" ../>
```

from inside

```
<sj:tabbedpanel href=%{Overview}.../>
```

but I am unable to access it , it gives blank value!

options I have tried:

```
<sj:tab href=${Overview}..../>
```

It gave exception:"according to tld or attribute href, does not accept any expressions" ,

also tried `<sj:tab href=%{#Overview}..../>`

didnt gave any exception but it did not fetch any value either.

Please help!!